# How to embed data dependent animations in an MVC website

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

At work my boss requested I add in animations gauges and meters of different kinds to reflect the data presented. The website was built by a previous employee who coded it using ASP.NET MVC. I am not knowledgeable at all with web applications or website designs so I researched how to build and use MVC templates in visual studio. However, after all the searching I could not find how to embed animations that will reflect the data provided by the database in the website.

I did also try to look for pre-built animations that would take data inputs and animate/display them accordingly but did not find suitable results.

How can I go about doing this? and if there is a resource that goes over this in detail I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: what kind of animation? animation or chart?

Comment: "The website was built by a previous employee who coded it using ASP.NET MVC. I am not knowledgeable at all with web applications or website designs". Surely your employer does not expect that you will be able to become a web developer overnight. This is a skilled job that can take years to learn. I would suggest that you tell your employer that you he will need to employ a web developer or outsource this work to a web agency who specializes in this type of stuff.

Comment: The website displays data sent over by sensors. I am asked to show this data using animated meters, like for example, a tank filling with liquid to show the amount of fluids in a tank, or a half circular gauge like the ones you see in a car to display other measures like temperature or pressure. So simply put, animated meters/gauges/pictures that reflect the data inputted from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for charts that animate then ChartJs will do that:

https://www.chartjs.org/